# T-SQL :: information_type is not parsed in SQL Server 2019

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, data-masking, dynamic-data-masking

My query doesn't seems to parse `information_type`

> STEP TO REPRODUCE:

1. Take AdventureWork or any other test database
2. Right click on your test database > `Tasks > Data Discovery and Classification > Classify Data...` and classify a bunch of data
3. Now use this query to check your `information_type` column (here I'm using AdventureWork2019):

Paste this select and execute

```
SELECT 
    schema_name(O.schema_id) AS schema_name,
    O.NAME AS table_name,
    C.NAME AS column_name,
         [Type] = 
    CASE 
      WHEN ct.[name] IN ('varchar', 'char') THEN ct.[name] + '(' + IIF(c.max_length = -1, 'max', CAST(c.max_length AS VARCHAR(25))) + ')' 
      WHEN ct.[name] IN ('nvarchar','nchar') THEN ct.[name] + '(' + IIF(c.max_length = -1, 'max', CAST(c.max_length / 2 AS VARCHAR(25)))+ ')'      
      WHEN ct.[name] IN ('decimal', 'numeric') THEN ct.[name] + '(' + CAST(c.precision AS VARCHAR(25)) + ', ' + CAST(c.scale AS VARCHAR(25)) + ')'
      WHEN ct.[name] IN ('datetime2') THEN ct.[name] + '(' + CAST(c.scale AS VARCHAR(25)) + ')'
      ELSE ct.[name]
    END,
    information_type,
    label,
    rank,
    rank_desc,
    CAST(
             CASE
                  WHEN information_type = 'Contact Info' 
                     THEN 'contact info'
                  ELSE 'not contact info'
             END AS varchar(max)) as Checking_Content
FROM sys.sensitivity_classifications sc
    JOIN sys.objects O
    ON  sc.major_id = O.object_id
    JOIN sys.columns C 
    ON  sc.major_id = C.object_id  AND sc.minor_id = C.column_id
    JOIN sys.types ct ON C.user_type_id = ct.user_type_id
    --AND EP.minor_id = C.column_id
    order by information_type
```

As you can see the query is returning `not contact info` even when the column `information_type` has value `Contact Info`

| schema_name | table_name | column_name | Type | information_type | label | rank | rank_desc | Checking_Content |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Person | PersonPhone | PhoneNumber | Phone | Contact Info | Confidential | 20 | MEDIUM | not contact info |
| Person | PersonPhone | PhoneNumberTypeID | int | Contact Info | Confidential | 20 | MEDIUM | not contact info |
| Person | PhoneNumberType | PhoneNumberTypeID | int | Contact Info | Confidential | 20 | MEDIUM | not contact info |
| Person | Address | AddressLine1 | nvarchar(60) | Contact Info | Confidential | 20 | MEDIUM | not contact info |
| Person | Address | AddressLine2 | nvarchar(60) | Contact Info | Confidential | 20 | MEDIUM | not contact info |
| Person | Address | City | nvarchar(30) | Contact Info | Confidential | 20 | MEDIUM | not contact info |
| Person | Address | PostalCode | nvarchar(15) | Contact Info | Confidential | 20 | MEDIUM | not contact info |
| Production | ProductReview | EmailAddress | nvarchar(50) | Contact Info | Confidential | 20 | MEDIUM | not contact info |
| Person | EmailAddress | EmailAddress | nvarchar(50) | Contact Info | Confidential | 20 | MEDIUM | not contact info |
| dbo | ErrorLog | UserName | sysname | Credentials | Confidential | 20 | MEDIUM | not contact info |
| Person | Password | PasswordHash | varchar(128) | Credentials | Confidential | 20 | MEDIUM | not contact info |
| Person | Password | PasswordSalt | varchar(10) | Credentials | Confidential | 20 | MEDIUM | not contact info |
| Sales | CreditCard | CreditCardID | int | Credit Card | Confidential | 20 | MEDIUM | not contact info |
| Sales | CreditCard | CardType | nvarchar(50) | Credit Card | Confidential | 20 | MEDIUM | not contact info |
| Sales | CreditCard | CardNumber | nvarchar(25) | Credit Card | Confidential | 20 | MEDIUM | not contact info |
| Sales | CreditCard | ExpYear | smallint | Credit Card | Confidential | 20 | MEDIUM | not contact info |
| Sales | PersonCreditCard | CreditCardID | int | Credit Card | Confidential | 20 | MEDIUM | not contact info |
| Sales | SalesOrderHeader | CreditCardID | int | Credit Card | Confidential | 20 | MEDIUM | not contact info |
| Sales | SalesOrderHeader | CreditCardApprovalCode | varchar(15) | Credit Card | Confidential | 20 | MEDIUM | not contact info |
| HumanResources | Employee | BirthDate | date | Date Of Birth | Confidential - GDPR | 20 | MEDIUM | not contact info |

I'm very confused:

[image]

What do you think?

Comment: Try `LEN(information_type)` and I bet it's not what you expect. Then try to figure out if there are extra spaces, tabs, carriage returns, control characters, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to

```
exec sp_describe_first_result_set N'select * from sys.sensitivity_classifications sc'
```

information_type is a sql_variant.  Which is not per the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-sensitivity-classifications-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) but should not be an issue as compatible types are converted to sql_variant for comparison without issue.  EG

```
select case when  cast(N'Contact Info' as sql_variant) = 'Contact Info' then 1 else 0 end
```

returns

1

So this is potentially a bug.  You can work around by casting explitly to nvarchar. eg

```
SELECT 
    schema_name(O.schema_id) AS schema_name,
    O.NAME AS table_name,
    C.NAME AS column_name,
         [Type] = 
    CASE 
      WHEN ct.[name] IN ('varchar', 'char') THEN ct.[name] + '(' + IIF(c.max_length = -1, 'max', CAST(c.max_length AS VARCHAR(25))) + ')' 
      WHEN ct.[name] IN ('nvarchar','nchar') THEN ct.[name] + '(' + IIF(c.max_length = -1, 'max', CAST(c.max_length / 2 AS VARCHAR(25)))+ ')'      
      WHEN ct.[name] IN ('decimal', 'numeric') THEN ct.[name] + '(' + CAST(c.precision AS VARCHAR(25)) + ', ' + CAST(c.scale AS VARCHAR(25)) + ')'
      WHEN ct.[name] IN ('datetime2') THEN ct.[name] + '(' + CAST(c.scale AS VARCHAR(25)) + ')'
      ELSE ct.[name]
    END,
    information_type,
    label,
    rank,
    rank_desc,
    CAST(
             CASE
                  WHEN cast(information_type as nvarchar(200)) = 'Contact Info' 
                     THEN 'contact info'
                  ELSE 'not contact info'
             END AS varchar(max)) as Checking_Content
FROM sys.sensitivity_classifications sc
    JOIN sys.objects O
    ON  sc.major_id = O.object_id
    JOIN sys.columns C 
    ON  sc.major_id = C.object_id  AND sc.minor_id = C.column_id
    JOIN sys.types ct ON C.user_type_id = ct.user_type_id
    --AND EP.minor_id = C.column_id
    order by information_type
```

Comment: Thank you @DavidBrowne. Where should I report this?

Comment: I also found another bug: if you run `exec sp_describe_first_result_set N'select * from sys.masked_columns'` the column `masking_function` has collation `Latin1_General_CI_AS_KS_WS` and I cannot join it with other SYS tables because they are using `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS` (https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/sql-docs/issues/7054). This website looks more for feedback than bug report: https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/idea/de91db50-1752-ec11-a81a-6045bd78b970